# C# Oxyplot Horizontal boxplot

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I have a series of boxplots that I have created in Oxyplot that look like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7PpK.png).
Is it possible to plot these as horizontal box plots instead, so they look more like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBCZt.png)?
My code is as follows:

```
 var plot = new PlotModel();
        var items = new Collection<Item>();

        foreach (var item in MainWindow.classificationDistances)
        {
            items.Add(new Item { Label = item.Key.ToString() });
        }

        plot.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis
        {
            Position = AxisPosition.Left,
            MajorStep = 0.025,
            MinorStep = 0.005,
            Key = "Distance",
            TickStyle = TickStyle.Crossing,
            AbsoluteMaximum = 1,
            AbsoluteMinimum = -0.25
        });

        plot.Axes.Add(new CategoryAxis
        {
            Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
            ItemsSource = items,
            LabelField = "Label",                 
            Key = "Classification",
            IsTickCentered = true,
            TickStyle = TickStyle.None,
            IsZoomEnabled = false
        });


        var s1 = new BoxPlotSeries
        {
            Fill = OxyColor.FromRgb(0x1e, 0xb4, 0xda),
            StrokeThickness = 1.1,
            WhiskerWidth = 1
        };

        double x = 0;
        foreach (var item in MainWindow.classificationDistances)
        {                
            var values = new List<double>();
            foreach (var value in item.Value)
            {
                values.Add(value);
            }

            values.Sort();
            var median = getMedian(values);
            int r = values.Count % 2;
            double firstQuartil = getMedian(values.Take((values.Count + r) / 2)); // 25%-Quartil
            double thirdQuartil = getMedian(values.Skip((values.Count - r) / 2)); // 75%-Quartil

            var iqr = thirdQuartil - firstQuartil; // Quartilabstand
            var step = 1.5 * iqr;
            var upperWhisker = thirdQuartil + step;
            upperWhisker = values.Where(v => v <= upperWhisker).Max();
            var lowerWhisker = firstQuartil - step;
            lowerWhisker = values.Where(v => v >= lowerWhisker).Min();
            var outliers = values.Where(v => v > upperWhisker || v < lowerWhisker).ToList();

            s1.Items.Add(new BoxPlotItem(x, lowerWhisker, firstQuartil, median, thirdQuartil, upperWhisker));
            x++;
        }

        plot.Series.Add(s1);
        return plot;
```

Swapping the Linear and Category Axis positions does change the axis suitably, however, the data is [completely unreadable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsYD1.png).

Additionally, is it possible to plot the probability density, so I could end up with something like [this?](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1a/Boxplot_vs_PDF.svg)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I doubt there's an easy enough way of doing it that would be worth the effort: that's why there are separate `BarSeries` and `ColumnSeries`, otherwise one would be just an option away from the other. Moreover, from a data visualization point of you, overlaying a box plot series and a probability density function as you depicted in your question would be pointless, as it is not adding any insight into the data/information being presented.

Comment: @jsanalytics Thanks for your reply. That makes a lot of sense. If I wanted to plot a probability density function instead of the boxplots I have currently, would that be easily doable?

Comment: Yes, simply use either a line or scatter series.